# THREE.OBJLoader Multiple objects

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to load an object with OBJLoader and then I want to place it multiple times (without clone() ).

I tried:

```
var oLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
oLoader.load('cube.obj', function(object, materials) {

var material2 = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 0x00B74F });

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 

    object.traverse( function(child) {
        if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {

            // apply custom material
            child.material = material2;

            // enable casting shadows
            // child.castShadow = true;
            // child.receiveShadow = true;
        }
    });

    object.position.x = i * 1;
    object.position.y = i * 80;
    object.position.z = i * 100;
    object.scale.set(1, 1, 1);
    three.scene.add(object);
    console.log(object);
}

});
```

I probably need to create a new Mesh inside the `for` but I don't know what exactly I have to use.

Any help would be nice.

Thank you

Comment: Create an OBJLoader and call it's load function within the loop. But why would you not want to use clone?

Comment: call load method of OBJLoader inside the loop.